# Stop division from losing focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an autocomplete feature attached to an input tag with id keyword. The results of the autocomplete are visible in the division with id results and each result item inside a division with class item. 
Here is the HTML markup:

```
<input name='institute' type="text" placeholder="Start typing.."id="keyword">
<div id="results">
    <div class="item"><p>Item 1</p></div>
    <div class="item"><p>Item 2</p></div>
    <div class="item"><p>Item 3</p></div>
</div>
```

The division results has a fixed height. Here is the CSS:

```
width:80%;
height: 200px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Here is my the part of the jquery relevant to my question

```
$("#keyword").blur(function() {
    $("#results").fadeOut(500);
  })
  .focus(function() {
    $("#results").show();
  });
```

Now the problem occurs whenever the height of the results exceeds from 200px. I get a scroll but whenever i click of the scroll, the input tag keyword looses its focus and the division results fades away. I want to keep the division results when I use the scroll and fade it only after an item is selected. How do I fix it?

Comment: I had to read this twice to realize you meant the `<div>` tag, not actual division!

Comment: How about not fading them out when losing focus, but when clicking somewhere else or better when they click a "close" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, and a real challenge to get to work in both Chrome *and* IE:

```
var canBlur= true;

$('#results')
  .mousedown(function(event) {
    canBlur= event.target.id !== 'results';
  })

$(document)
  .mousemove(function() {
    if(!canBlur) {
      $('#keyword').focus();
    }
    canBlur= true;
  });

$('#keyword')
  .blur(function(event) {
    if(canBlur) {
      $('#results').fadeOut(500);
    }
  })
  .focus(function() {
    $('#results').fadeIn(0);
  })
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/os9pz640/)

Answer (score 0):

When the user scrolls, they hold down the scrollbar and drag. You should make it so the `div` doesn't fade away if the user's mouse is down on the div. You should only make it fade away of both the `input` and the `div` are out of focus.

Answer (score 0):

Use the keypress event instead of blur like this

```
$("#keyword").keypress(function () { 
    $("#results").fadeOut(500);
}).focus(function () {
    $("#results").show();
});
```